# Custom taxonomy (categories) on custom post type return no results

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Hi everybody and thanks in advance for helping.

I am experiencing a problem with the categories I have created for my custom post type: when I click on the URL of the category (every category) I get the query error message. It is not a 404 page, it just seems that Wordpress cannot retrieve posts from the taxonomy.

This is code I have used into my functions.php to enable post type and taxonomy:

```
function themes_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'video_categories',
        'video',
        array(
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'label'             => 'Categories',
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array(
                'slug'          => 'category-video',
                'with_front'    => true
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'themes_taxonomy');

function custom_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Video', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                => 'video',
        'with_front'          => true,
        'pages'               => true,
        'feeds'               => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'video', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Videos', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'post-formats', 'custom-fields' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => false,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'taxonomies' => array('video_categories'), 
    );
    register_post_type( 'video', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

I have already tried flushing cache for urls by updating permalinks but nothing. The archive page works fine for Post Categories therefore it can't be an error on that.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, I just tested it.

Consider the following: Sometimes you may have a blog and you want URLS to beset up like `.xyz/DATE/POSTNAME` or perhaps you have a picture website and want it to be `.xyz/category/image`.

Luckily, Wordpress has built-in functionality to handle this. They are known as `Permalinks` - you just need set yours up in the desired manner.

To do this, go to the `WP admin menu -> settings -> permalinks`

Then at the bottom, select 'custom structure' and enter `/%category%/%postname%/` in the box. When you assign multiple categories to a post, only one can show up in the permalink.

To get around this, we can use the `%` symbols tells WordPress that this part of the URL is interchangeable.

Then hit save and try to load a post.

For more information on Permalinks, see [here](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-permalinks/).

Comment: Awesome. I was trying something similar and ur solution worked. Can you please explain why the happens?

Comment: @SiddharthVitthaldas I've tried to add more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> I get the query error message.

What exactly is the error?

Are you using a `pre_get_posts` filter? Something like:

```
function video_query_post_type($query) {
  if(is_category() || is_tag()) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if($post_type)
        $post_type = $post_type;
    else
        $post_type = array('post','video');
    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
  }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'video_query_post_type');
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for yor answer. The error I am getting is the classic "Posts not found." which is enabled if the query does not find any post. I am not using pre_get_posts: should I? At the moment, my the custom post type taxonomy is called through archive.php.

Comment: try the pre_get_posts filter